# Firebase Analytics is disabled. Event not logged.Ads doesn't appear

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm using Google Ads for my mobile app. Some of reasons ads doens't appear to app.

GoogleService-Info.plist is installed.

> UPDATES :I created Admob Payment İnformation and updated simulator version 10.0 to 12.0 and this problem solved.

I added this 2 lines into my info.plist but didn't work :

```
<key>FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED</key>
<string>NO</string>
<key>FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED</key>
<string>YES</string>
```

My AppDelegate.swift :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {  
FirebaseApp.configure()
GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "My Firebase App id")
}
```

My ViewController.swift :

```
@IBOutlet weak var vieww: GADBannerView! // There is a view that GADBannerView Class
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]

    vieww.adUnitID = "Banner ID from Admob"
    vieww.rootViewController = self
    vieww.load(request)

}
```

Debug screen :

> 5.15.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023049] Analytics is disabled. Event not logged

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering if anyone ever came up with a concrete solution for this, as I am in contact with the Firebase team troubleshooting this same issue on my own app that was hoping to push to beta this week, but am still waiting for a fix for this, as I really want to get Analytics working first. Unfortunately, none of the proposed fixes have turned up anything for me. I have payment options setup for AdMob, and interestingly, AdMob has been working just fine in my testing, but Analytics still wont. I have tried removing the app entirely from Firebase and starting with a from scratch with Firebase, but the issue still remains. I have also tried adjusting the plist file entry IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED to both yes and no, and still same results. I have tried removing the GoogleService-Info.plist file and using the one AdMob generates and also the one Firebase generates, but no dice either way. I have also tried to add.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    AnalyticsConfiguration.shared().setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
    GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "id number")
```

}

Nothing has worked. Any ideas??????

Here is an example of what I see in my logs in XCode:

[Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID023000] No info is retrieved from Keychain
OSStatus: -25300 with the keychain query

5.16.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023049] Analytics is disabled. Event not logged

[Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID023002] Couldn't delete item from Keychain

After hours long troubleshooting this. I figured it out. I had found a post that the had the answer, but thought it was referring to GoogleService-Info.plist and not the regular info.plist file, but the problem isn't with GoogleService one, its in the info.plist that is built into every iOS app, which I am guessing Firebase adds two entries to when it installs. This was the problem entry. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSrkR.png)

It needs to be set to NO to work correct, but probably defaults to NO for security reasons. Google needs to update Firebase Docs to reflect this change, but haven't yet. I will pass this onto the engineer I'm in contact with. Hope this helps someone else too.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day. Totally forget that there is info.plist. :face_palm

Answer (score 0):

In declaration of your `ViewController` do you conform to GADBannerViewDelegate?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {
```

Comment: You have to conform to GADBannerViewDelegate, and if it is still not working. Are you sure you added the view properly? Are you adding it on storyboard? Also those 2 lines in info.plist are redundant.

Comment: I added all things that you said but still don't work